# How to make a strechable image according to label height in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have objective-c code but i want swift code. please suggest me a swift code. i have tried all the ways but unable to find the proper answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey mate please find below code if it helps you

```
var lbl = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(8,8, 240, CGFloat.max))
    lbl.numberOfLines = 0
    lbl.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
    lbl.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 16.0)
    lbl.text = "Sample text"
    lbl.sizeToFit()

    let imageContainerMessage = UIImage(named: "balloon_unread_left.png")!.stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth(15, topCapHeight: 17 )
    let sizeMessageLabelMax = CGSizeMake(240, 9999)
    let expectedSizeMessage = lbl.sizeThatFits(sizeMessageLabelMax)
    lbl.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 15, y: 10), size: expectedSizeMessage)

    var imageContainer = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), size: CGSizeMake(expectedSizeMessage.width + 25, expectedSizeMessage.height +  25)))
    imageContainer.image = imageContainerMessage

    imageContainer.addSubview(lbl)
```

Comment: I'm exactly looking for that..
u made atleast one man happy today :)